# using "CON" as filename

Tags: powershell, reserved-words

I was copying a huge number of png and txt files using `Copy-Item` cmdlet, and sadly I discovered that a funny programmer decided to use "CON" as file name to recap connection information.

Given that "con" is a reserved word and `Copy-Item` returns:

> Copy-Item : Cannot process path 'xxx\con.txt' because the target represents a reserved device name.

and given that this name can't be changed and it's used in every folder I need to copy, 
Is there a way to copy all these "con.cfg" and "con.txt" files using Powershell?

I googled but I found only advice like "Don't use con!" or "Don't use Powershell to copy these files".

Comment: Haha, I can't even create a file named 'con.txt' to replicate your problem, but I think that [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/129260) on superuser can help you

Comment: use linux boot cd to copy the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a solution for PowerShell yet, but you should be able to rename the files via command prompt using something like this:

```
ren \\.\<absolute path> <new name>
```

So for example:

```
ren \\.\C:\stuff\con.cfg stuff.cfg
```

You could invoke the command prompt through PowerShell, of course:

```
cmd /c "ren \\.\C:\stuff\con.cfg stuff.cfg"
```

And obviously you could use PowerShell variables in there if you wanted

```
$dir = "C:\stuff"
cmd /c "ren \\.\$dir\con.cfg stuff.cfg"
```

Comment: I can't get it working with remote paths like `\\servername\c$\myPath` but it works locally... better then nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You could try referring to them using a wildcard: `*on` ?

**Example:**

```
ls | ? {$_.Name -match "*on.cfg"} | del
```

**Regex example:**

```
ls | ? {$_.Name -match "^\won\.cfg"} | del
```

Comment: my problem is creating a file with that name